# iOS Push Notifications Question

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have never coded an App with Push Notifications, and I have a very general question.  Does the publisher of the App have control to push out a notification whenever they want after the App is released on the App store?  I mean, for example, if an App has push notifications enabled, is there some sort of dashboard somewhere where the App developer can instantaneously push out a notification to everyone that has downloaded the App?  (Assuming they have push notifications enabled)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your app supports Push Notifications, you have to provide your own server that communicates with Apple's push infrastructure.  You can implement whatever sort of dashboard you want in your server.  (In lieu of actually providing this yourself, you could also use a third-party provider such as Urban Airship.)

An overview of how your provider interacts with Apple's service is here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html

Comment: Is there some sort of review process by Apple?  I mean, I have a server that sends out a Push Notification at 8 AM, will it be instantaneous, or is there a delay?

Comment: A popular dashboard/push notification management service is Urban Airship http://urbanairship.com/

Comment: Are you asking whether somebody at Apple will review every individual notification to every device before letting it go to the device?  No.  Notifications go out basically immediately, although there may be a slight delay due to load on Apple's server and network, and if a device is offline, then it won't receive notification until it goes online.

Comment: What I was trying to figure out is this - if I wrote an App for my local bakery and they wanted to send out a message telling everyone who had downloaded it that they were having a 50% off sale, how timely would it be?  However, I just read somewhere that it seems that Apple restricts using Push notifications in this way...

Comment: @Rob Can you please share the source for the Apple restrictions? I'm looking into a similar situation myself. Thanks!