# ios push notification for multiple devices

Tags: php, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have the following php code for ios push notification.Here i code for 2 devices using loop in fwrite() section . the current code is working properly . My doubt is , can i pass the array of device tokens directly without using the for loop?.

```
<?php
// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken[0] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$deviceToken[1] = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = '123456';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'multiple device push notification...!';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'abc.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
'alert' => $message,
'sound' => 'default',
'badge' => '+1'
);

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++)
{
// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken[$i]) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) .     $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
echo "msg may be delivered";
}

if (!$result)
echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS Push Notifications Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504448/ios-push-notifications-question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its `design by default`, yet there is no option for passing array of device tokens. You have to iterate through the loop.

Comment: Is there any alternate option available, I can create an array of device_tokens to upload with apple payload and notification goes to all devices specified in an array lets say for ex. 1000 users or more? please help

Comment: Its design by default, you can not send array you have to loop through all the device token's array to send to multiple push notification.

Comment: My code is almost same as above, though when I am trying to send push to multiple devices, (fwrite to each `device_id`), it works if I have an array of 2-3 device IDs (have only tested on that much), but does not work when I have ~300 device IDs

Answer (score 0):

Alternate to this approach will be using third party like [amazon SNS service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/welcome.html). Here you can publish to topic(one request) and all devices that are subscribed to this topic will receive the notification.